# How to take random samples of variable size from a dataframe

Tags: r, resampling

This is probably a simple problem, but I've been struggling to find a solution. I would like to automate the sampling of rows from a `dataframe`, but I would like to iteratively increase the size of the sample (number of rows sampled) until the sample size equals the length of the`dataframe`.

To demonstrate my goal, I'll provide a very long-handed example:

```
data<-data.frame(replicate(6,sample(0:1,10,rep=TRUE)))

samples<-list()
samples[[1]]<-data[sample(nrow(data), 2),]
samples[[2]]<-data[sample(nrow(data), 4),]
samples[[3]]<-data[sample(nrow(data), 6),]
#... until:
samples[[10]]<-data[sample(nrow(data),10),]
```

Comment: `samples <- lapply(seq_len(nrow(data)), function(n) data[sample(nrow(data), n),])`

Comment: If you'd like the size of the samples to go 2,4,6 ... use @IceCreamToucan 's code and change `seq_len(nrow(data))` for `seq(2,nrow(data),by=2`

Comment: Perfect! @IceCreamToucan's code, with boski's generalization for other intervals, has solved it.